# Confluent for Kubernetes can't access kafka externally

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I'm trying to create an external access about confluent-kafka from an AKS cluster. I've been able to connect with control center with an Ingress but i can't create the external access from kafka.
I added this to spec of kafka:

```
listeners:
    external:
      externalAccess:
        type: loadBalancer
        loadBalancer: 
          domain: lb.example.it
          advertisedPort: 39093
```

and it creates two load-balancer services. Then i added the external IPs on my etc/hosts file:

```
20.31.10.27    kafka.lb.example.it
20.31.9.167    b0.lb.example.it
```

But when i ceate a nodejs producer i don't know what to put into broker:

```
const { Kafka } = require('kafkajs')
const kafka = new Kafka({
  clientId: 'my-app',
  brokers: ['kafka.lb.example.it:39093']
})

const producer = kafka.producer()
console.log("produced")


const asyncOperation = async () => {
  console.log("connecting")
await producer.connect()
console.log("connected")
let i = 0

try{
  while(true){
  await producer.send({
    topic: 'topic_prova3',
    messages: [
                {
                  key: JSON.stringify("hello"),
                  value: JSON.stringify({"NUM":i}),
                },
              ]
            })
  await producer.send({
    topic: 'topic_prova3',
    messages: [
                {
                  value: JSON.stringify({"NUMERO":i.toString()}),
                },
              ]
            })
  console.log("sended")
  i++
await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));

}
}
catch(err){
  console.error("error: " + err)
}
await producer.disconnect()
}

asyncOperation();
```

This is the log of the error:

```
{"level":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-01-22T08:43:20.761Z","logger":"kafkajs","message":"[Connection] Connection error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.2:9092","broker":"kafka-0.kafka.ckafka.svc.cluster.local:9092","clientId":"my-app","stack":"Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.2:9092\n    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1495:16)"}
```

The broker should be `kafka.ckafka.svc.cluster.local:9092` , instead of `kafka-0.kafka.ckafka.svc.cluster.local:9092` but it does it automatically

Comment: Do you really need Confluent operator? https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/04/17/accessing-kafka-part-1/

Comment: I use Confluent because it has even connectors and ksqldb that is the scope of my project

Comment: You can use both of those without their Kubernetes Operator

Answer (score 2):

The load balancer appears to be working (it's not throwing unknown host exception), and it returned a cluster local broker address. See above comment that explains why this happens within Kubernetes with Kafka.

You need to modify, or use, the appropriate `advertised.listeners` port that corresponds to the external LoadBalancer.

> from an AKS cluster.

You should use Azure services to create a public DNS route rather than specifically target one IP of your cluster for any given service in /etc/hosts; especially when you'd deploy multiple replicas of the Kafka pod.